# Difficult to do mod rewrite

Tags: apache

I am beginner in Apache rewrite URL.

I have a problem to rewrite URL.

I would like to rewrite www.test.com/abc/index.php?val=123 to www.test.com/abc/123/index.php

Note: abc is folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/index.php $1/index.php?val=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression in the RewriteRule made no sense. In addition you cannot reference parts of the query string in a RewriteRule, so you have to additionally use a RewriteCond to capture the query arguments.

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} val=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule  ^(.+)/index.php $1/%1/index.php [L]
```

It is always a good idea to have apache itself help you with debugging expressions: use the logging feature: read the documentation for the two commands `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`. They dump each step taken and allow to understand what is actually happening inside the algorithm.

All information required is offered in the [fine documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It really is worth working through...

Comment: I try to type  test.com/abc/123/index.php but it was error .The requested URL /abc/123 was not found on this server.

Comment: Well yes, if such folder does not exist that error makes sense. You wrote in your question that this is the final url you want to rewrite requests to: `www.test.com/abc/123/index.php`. This requests a file `index.php` inside a folder `123`.

Comment: but it has abc folder in my web directory. why it was error ? 123 is not folder please see this test.com/abc/index.php?val=123 to test.com/abc/123/index.php. Hope you understand.

Comment: Sorry, I do _not_ understand. Obviously `123` is not a folder, that is why you get an error. But you state again that you want a rewrite to a file in that folder. a rewrite to the local path `/abc/123/index.php`. If this is _not_ what you want (which I assume) then you have to explain what resouce you actually _do_ want to rewrite requests to. The `123` is what YOU ask for in your question!

Comment: I want to convert index.php?val=123  to /123/index.php. Can we do that ?

Comment: But that is exactly what happens right now. You yourself ask for a folder called `123` yet you complain that that folder does not exist. Why do you want to rewrite to a folder `123` when it does not exist? Direct question: where (absolute path) is that `index.php` file you want to rewrite to?

Comment: I _think_ I have an idea: could it be you actually want to rewrite the opposite way? So that when you enter `http://www.test.com/abc/123/index.php` into a browser that internally this request is called: `/abc/index.php?val=123`? This would be a typical thing often done: to prevent 'ugly' request arguments. You question clearly askes the other way around, but maybe there is a missunderstanding on your side on how http requests actually work...

Comment: 123 is not folder but it is value. so which way is better ? can you guide me?

Comment: Sorry. No way to help or guide you if you fail to explain what you actually want to do. We all know `123` by now is not a folder in your system. But in your question you ask for a rewrite to a file `/abc/123/index.php`. Sorry, your question does not make sense. What do you want?!?

Comment: Dear arkascha. This is my original url ( test.com/abc/index.php?val=123), so i want to convert this url to test.com/abc/123/index.php. 123 is val=123.It is possible convert from val=123 to 123/index.php ?Do you understand what i mean? Regards Jam

Comment: Sorry, repeating the same line again and again does not help. I can NOT understand what you mean that way. Why don't you answer my questions? Why don't you explain what you want in plain terms instead of using that obviously wrong RewriteRule again and again. What do you want to type in a browser and where is that index.php file located? Answer these questions.

Comment: Dear. index.php in abc folder

Comment: Ok, that was an answer to one question. What about the other questions? If `index.php` is located inside folder `abc` then its position is `/abc/index.php`. Why do you want to rewrite to `/abc/123/index.php` then instead if that folder does not exist? Aparently you did not understand how rewriting works. Therefore my other question was: what is the url you want to type into the browser so that that index.php file is called the way you want to?

Comment: The reason that i want to rewrite to /abc/123/index.php because in abc folder has index.php and have one arugment that contain value. Example is /abc/index.php?val=123,So i want to convert it to /abc/123/index.php by remove val Regards,

Comment: Ok, this is the point where I give up. Again you just repeat the same thing instead of really explaining or answering questions. Did you turn on logging as I explained in my answer to learn more and find the cause of the problem? No? Why not? Why don't you answer simple questions, but instead repeat the same expression again and again? Why don't you say what url should be requested, so typed into a browser? Why don't you react on the fact that I explained multiple times that YOU YOURSELF ask for file `/abc/123/index.php` when you want "to rewrite to" that location? Sorry, I am out...

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this rule in htaccess file add a `RewriteBase` directive

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```